# Check if url matches mask in aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

Here is the aiohttp server initialising:

```py
self.app = web.Application()
self.app.add_routes([
    web.get('/{endpoint:.*}', self.handle),
    web.post('/{endpoint:.*}', self.handle),
    web.options('/{endpoint:.*}', self.handle),
    web.put('/{endpoint:.*}', self.handle),
])
runner = web.AppRunner(self.app)
await runner.setup()
site = web.TCPSite(runner, **self.config)
await site.start()
```

and handle function looks something like this:

```py
async def handle(self, request):
    endpoint = request.match_info['endpoint']
    if endpoint == 'api/user/{user_id}/':
        some_stuff()
```

How can I check if the request URL matches the endpoint mask? It's easy to add this mask to `add_routes`, but I'm looking for an alternative solution without any changes in initialising.

Comment: Are you just trying to do string matching? Have you considered using a regular expression like `re.findall(f'api/user/[0-9]+/', endpoint)`?

Comment: @xjcl I've already found another library to do it using reverse format - https://pypi.org/project/parse/. However, I think that this function must be in the aiohttp lib.